# Passing a Soap message from PHP

Tags: php, soap

I know almost nothing about PHP. So I have a coworker doing the PHP stuff. It's not going well so I need some help.

Here is the task.

1. Receive a SOAP message (in this case from SalesForce) in a PHP site on Linux.
2. Take that soap message and simply pass it along to a web service (as a parameter) running on a windows server. Which I am writing. The reason we need to do it this way is far beyond the scope of this question. We have no choice.

The communication between the PHP page and the webservice works.  The problem is taking the soap message and sending it to the method in the webservice as a parameter.

Here is the big question:
How can we accept a soap message and send it as a prameter. Even converting it to a simple string and sending that would work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without examples of what you've tried, you're basically asking someone on SO to write the solution for you.  Still to be fair, there are generally two ways to pass information into a PHP web script.  As GET arguments (ex /myScript.php?message=Foo ) and as a POST where the information is encoded.

Comment: Not possible to answer unless you give more details about the windows service. Does it take a query string? Is it a soap method? Is it rest? What did you write it in? and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you need to use a SOAP handler, and then reformat the request accordingly.

I'd suggest you start by taking a look at NuSOAP, which provides PHP SOAP support. Go here - [for a nifty tutorial on NuSOAP](http://www.codedeveloper.net/2010/05/nusoap-soap-php-web-services-tutorial-part-one/)